# IPSEC VPN algorithm changes in Sonoma/Apple Silicon?

Tags: macos, vpn, apple-silicon, configuration-profiles

I recently got a new M3 MBP to replace my old Intel model, which also necessitated an upgrade to Sonoma from Ventura. My VPN configuration is via a mobile configuration profile that has worked fine for a while. It specifies the following P1 settings:

```xml
<key>IKESecurityAssociationParameters</key>
<dict>
    <key>DiffieHellmanGroup</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
    <key>EncryptionAlgorithm</key>
    <string>AES-256-GCM</string>
    <key>IntegrityAlgorithm</key>
    <string>SHA2-384</string>
    <key>LifeTimeInMinutes</key>
    <integer>480</integer>
</dict>
```

But when I tried to connect to my company VPN for the first time on my new MBP I was unable to. Digging into logs on our router, I found macOS was ignoring the profile settings and sending these proposals:

```
IKE:AES_GCM_16_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_256
IKE:AES_GCM_16_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_256
IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
```

This is different than previous versions, as my router was configured to only accept this:

```
IKE:AES_GCM_16_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/ECP_384
```

The only contemporary OS changes I could find documented were the removal of some [super-old and insecure](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvos-release-notes/tvos-17-release-notes#NetworkExtension) protocols from tvOS and watchOS 17.

Is this a documented change related either to Sonoma or my architecture change?

Comment: There a certainly undocumented VPN changes in Sonoma. For example: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sonoma-bug-ikev2-vpn-no-longer-rekeys-so-vpn-connections-drop-every-20-25-minutes.2406029/